# Why Illustrator file is opened cropped and distorted in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, adobe-photoshop, distort, import

in order to be able to export in jpg some files made in illustrator i'm using Photoshop to finish this process.

The fact is that I've noticed that Photoshop open the file cropped and distorted.

The original file has 16.383px X 10.000px.

As you can see in the image the brutal crop and distortion I've tried to open and open as smart object in Photoshop but the result is the same.

What can I do?

[image: difference between the original Illustrator file and the photoshop imported file]

[image: image inside the artboard]

[image: artboard settings]

Comment: Is all the AI artwork actually on the AI artboard? Have you altered what the PDF Open dialog uses as the defining area?

Comment: Yes the file is in the artwork. The 16.383 is also the max allowed by my Illustrator. Regarding the PDF oped dialog I've altered the size but the result is always the same.

Comment: What Scott is asking is if all the artwork in your `.ai` file is inside the bounds of the ***artboard*** - if not, that might explain the trimming.

Comment: I just posted a new image in the post so you can see the artboard! I don't understand. And it's not just trimming, it's distorting too.

Comment: Okay.. then what are the [**import options**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AKm1T.png) set to when importing the file?  If this is set incorrectly it may be causing the issue. Ultimately though - if everything is on the artboard and import options *are* set correctly - I think this is a file-specific issue which probably can't be solved on a message board without direct file examination (making this off topic).

Comment: I gotta admit though.. if *that* is the artwork, why it need to remain vector is a mystery to me. There may be a valid reason, but I can't think of one for any of my workflows. I'd export as raster..tiff/jpg and open *that* with Photoshop.

Comment: You *might* also try reducing the Ai artwork in Illustrator so it's not exactly at the artboard limits of Illustrator. You can reduce the AI artwork then increase the scale when exporting if necessary.

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. Unfortunately I can't replicate this problem. Sounds like this is a file specific issue. Without access to the AI, there's probably no way investigate what is going on.

Comment: Scott, the fact is that I'm unable to export from Illustrator. It crashes. I'm trying all possible ways to get this jpg for print. I need a large file with high resolution.

Comment: What I would do.... reduce the AI artwork by 50%. Save as PDF. Open a new Photoshop document at the size you need. Then File > Place the PDF as a smart object and enlarge it 150% to fit the Photoshop document.

Answer (score 1):

You must uncheck: Preferences > General > Resize image During Place.

When it's enabled, your image or vector will fit the canvas if it's larger than the canvas.

When it's disabled, your image or vector will be placed on with the right dimensions.

See the image below.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For myself, I would *not* "**Open**" the illustrator file in Photoshop, I would "**Place>Linked**", which brings in the `.ai` as a Smart Object, and allows you to jump to and fro between Photoshop and Illustrator as needed in your creative process.

That said, I'm curious why you need to pull your `.ai` into Photoshop simply to export `.jpg` when Illustrator exports out `.jpg` rather nicely?

Comment: I've did it but the result is the same. Regarding why using Photoshop to export is because Illustrator says that the file is too big to be exported and ask me to reduce the size.

Comment: I am betting that some of your artwork is *outside* the bounds of your ***artboard***, hence the trimming.

Comment: I just inserted a new image in the post so you can see that the file is inside the artboard. I'm trying everything but nothing is working.